# How to make slider in/visible in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I need your help with making a slider invisible and visible in a `Manipulate`.
Here is my code:

```
Manipulate[{}, 
  {x, 0, 1}, 
  {y, 0, 1}, 
  {visible, 
    {"only x-slider visible", "only y-slider visible", "both visible"}, 
    ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

The `PopupMenu` shows how I want it to function.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option:

```
Manipulate[{},
  Dynamic@If[visible != "hide x-slider",
             Control[{x, 0, 1}],
             Invisible@Control[{x, 0, 1}]], 
  {visible, {"hide x-slider", "show x-slider"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok, the part
     `DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@If[]]`
I see nowhere before. Thanks for your help.
Is there any other possibility to solve that problem?
I can use x only as a normal slider, but can't open this slider with the plus...

Comment: @Manu See edit please

Comment: Ok, very well :-)
Thanks

Comment: I have another possibility without using `Invisible@Control[]`:
        `Manipulate[{},
         Dynamic@If[visible != "hide x-slider", 
           Column[{Control[{x, 0, 1}], Control[{y, 0, 1}]}], 
           Control[{y, 0, 1}]],
         {visible, {"hide x-slider", "show x-slider"}, 
         ControlType -> PopupMenu}]`

Comment: @Manu I used _Invisible[]_ on purpose to preserve the appearance of the manipulate dialog

Comment: I know, you only answered my question

Answer (score 4):

A couple more ways.

[`PaneSelector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PaneSelector.html), with a blank [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Row.html):

```
Manipulate[{x, y},
 PaneSelector[{True -> Control[{x, 0, 1}], False -> Row[{}]}, 
   Dynamic[visible != "only y-slider visible"]],
 PaneSelector[{True -> Control[{y, 0, 1}], False -> Row[{}]}, 
   Dynamic[visible != "only x-slider visible"]],
 {visible, {"only x-slider visible", "only y-slider visible", 
            "both visible"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) switch between [`Identity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Identity.html) & [`Invisible`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Invisible.html):

```
Manipulate[{x, y},
 Dynamic[If[visible != "only y-slider visible", Identity, Invisible]@
   Control[{x, 0, 1}]],
 Dynamic[If[visible != "only x-slider visible", Identity, Invisible]@
   Control[{y, 0, 1}]],
 {visible, {"only x-slider visible", "only y-slider visible", 
            "both visible"}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So now I have a lot of possibilitys :-)

Comment: @Manu, make sure you've got that:  Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!